Cycling of Lexicographic simplex method
I am studying the cycling of simplex method. I know that there is a lexicographic rule to prevent looping of the simplex method, and I also know that this rule should be applied to a lexicographically valid simplex table (this is a table in which the first non-zero coefficients are positive). But I know that there is a way to loop the lexicographic simplex method, for this you need to select the appropriate lexicographically invalid simplex table. Can you please help with this task (I also know that at least such a table has a dimension of 3(constraints) by 7(variables))
